# Erro no context-root javaEE usando Jboss

Tags: java

Estou com um projeto com erro, tenho estás mensagens de erro nos arquivos de configuração: 404 - Not Found

jboos-web.xml
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
web.xml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Po favor, não coloque código como imagem. Fica bem ruim de ler.

Answer (score 0):

O `context-root` não deve incluir a barra. Deve ser apenas:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>matriz</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Para que isso tenha efeito, remova o projeto do servidor e faça o deploy novamente.